# Pass Token and Headers for a post request using powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, soap, automation

I am trying to make post request to rest service using Invoke-WebRequest in powershell but I keep getting Auth token not valid even though I can use the same token and header for validation in SOAP UI tool. Everything works fine in tool but I am having issues in powershell. Below is the sample code that I am using to make a call.

```
$postparams3= @{AuthToken="$FinalToken"}
$FinalHeader= @{Cookie="$CookieHeader"}
$output3= Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://someexample.com/api/getdetails -Method Post -Body $postparams3 -Headers $FinalHeader
```

Below is the sample token and Header that I am trying to pass using powershell. I use the same values in SOAP UI tool as well. SOAP UI was able to make successful call but not powershell

$FinalToken=zB4NXuwipxZqcydsQnHDBrHFL3Nfa+7SbfFbmQ==xuHhzt0taggkMGBC

$CookieHeader=ASP.NET_SessionId=xe50hv0lgthr0k5mdxm34et3; path=/; HttpOnly,.ASPXAUTH=88AA5E47660EF385C09A5EE576995BAC7F88ABE70938DAD861C3F2C29599BB97D020A2D11F874FC7B6864123C5D9B18C80F61B8FBBCC2AE2FC4FE34586F990A908ED247FDF13DF7195B5598BF8100A2FE21201F80FBC6DABB1F55F278C3B264
E; path=/,4228470b1fa65b0d5432813abdb97e97=6A7614B979259F2206918E0475D52EDD47A2EB2B5A69A459DD3764E77DE63642A2A3B8929F2411E0AEE65627FD5C39607816995296626DA7295CA870CF4506AF2FA502B4551D893CB8156D2FF1FE119F6D63D259CE1DCA4F2472724A7395E482422A3CDC0B54DDF11207F81600F
18A112BA754694E62121BE7FB992D1F22BFB4DE1CCFCD6DF09D494726EEB0B903BB7DC692FF02E386DB629FF9A2336DCC832B28FA1A6E7D0B4D4E2D8CF26281CF6B83ACE9638F238ED6294378E5F0F0DE0D5CDA176FC06E885B2738914535D49FBB7553A25648ADB44B531026EABD6F1DB10B54F9766A7BA7CCE329D4A15DD05ED8449
C18CFA29203AE123AACDF0CAEDB048D40A0E79B9DC5FC31720C07B0B55F82461476C5CFF520686CEE0FAF97F34F13ADFDA29E5CD402EDA9AE82BA486BC363F73863C0CBA9CD3F071E86A67531287706F70F9C539E946DC8BED67BD8E0534172CBA27CA105E5D0DFC6CF8D9A11A6D0B8C04645F61944B9458D18D89822829C27DEFCD3F
DDF88BB14EB315C752B9EF9B9D0E00A9E78D5D166BF37999BE17A130CC2AD4AF6991F01F12BC9924B6AFB17D759FA0E4BF7AE48971DCFAEA2D38F084B631BDD2D4BA288525AFFDEDAAAE1095276D8C1002316D3FD08774B256252119EB9420616FDCBE23E097E1AE4B91568E5BA48BBD81A7D46133CF429B8E61A9EEFBEC30EBB410AE
C33408E80AA4BD4B91D7DFF251AAA44D132C7AA4BC5CE14BA55DEDEE4A529B39D7F445DE0FD6ADA4615E147446EB69E190DE21B7E56AB9CD75155448FB4F433A8D2BE54EA9D8C847266A7C0D3023F8B1A05B1B7A5561A7E3F9E33E21B2086817B51356C38C54E4A1D5E223BCCFE0E8A99FE1AC66D0C9AC92F76; expires=Thu, 18-S
ep-2014 00:29:26 GMT; path=/

Comment: Post the full error..

Comment: I am getting No Authentication Provided error for my post request

Comment: Below is the exact error                                             StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"Code":110,"Message":"Authentication Token not provided"}

Comment: Use fiddler or the like to inspect you session, there will be a cookie or a header that's missing or you might be passing values in incorrect format(string vs b64 encoded string or something of this ilk)